# function in activeDataProvider output returning HTML in yii2

Tags: yii2, cactivedataprovider

```
[
  'label' => 'stars',
  'value' => function($model){

    $stars = $model->score;
    $result = "";
    for($i=1; $i<=$stars;$i++){ 
        $result .= "<span class='star'>☆</span>";
    }
    return $result;
  },
],
```

Given the above, I need to display the stars only, but I get bellow in the produced grid:

```
<span class='star'>☆</span> <span class='star'>☆</span> <span class='star'>☆</span>
```

But I want 3 styled stars.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `format` as **html** in **GridView** Columns option like below

```
[
  'label' => 'stars',
  'value' => function($model){
      $stars = $model->score;
      $result = "";
      for($i=1; $i<=$stars;$i++){ 
          $result .= "<span class='star'>☆</span>";
      }
      return $result;
  },
  'format' => 'html'
],
```

Refer [Yii2 Grid Data Columns Format](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$format-detail)

Answer (score 1):

```
         [
            'label' => 'stars',
            'format'=>'html', // Use this Line
            'value' => function($model){

                $stars = $model->score;
                $result = "";
                for($i=1; $i<=$stars;$i++){
                    $result .= '<i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                }
                return $result;
            },
        ],
```